# Form Control Properties in Partial Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to make some form control like Minimize, Exit and drag form but seems not work. I think the problem with partial class but after searching, I can't find solution to make this work.

Note: I can't remove namespace and partial for some reason. What must I change, maybe declare etc?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;

    namespace test
    {   
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

//Minimize (Not Work)
            private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
                {
                    notifyTray.Visible = true;
                    notifyTray.ShowBalloonTip(500);
                    this.Hide();
                }

                else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
                {
                    notifyTray.Visible = false;
                }
            }

//Exit (Not Work)
            private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                var window = MessageBox.Show("Wanna Close?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (window == DialogResult.No) e.Cancel = true;
                else e.Cancel = false;
            }

//Drag (Not Work)
        public bool _dragging = false;
        public Point _offset;
        public Point _start_point = new Point(0, 0);

        void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragging = true;  // _dragging is your variable flag
            _start_point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragging = false;
        }

        void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_dragging)
            {
                Point p = PointToScreen(e.Location);
                Location = new Point(p.X - this._start_point.X, p.Y - this._start_point.Y);
            }
        }
```

In VB that code works fine.

Comment: Are the code in the method is getting executed? Debug and check. If not hook up the handlers to their corresponding events.

Comment: Have you added event handlers for all these events (in code or using designer)? Are they called?

Comment: I try to make label give text "OK" if the method is executed, but there is no string in label. So I assume the event somehow not works. I try in VB, its work. No Error and warning. Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: @Tony : Im sorry, Im kinda interest with your comment, normally in VB I just use that code without add event handlers. How I can check the event handlers for that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Tony means is that in the Designer of your form you hook the handlers such as

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.FormClosing);
```

and this is where it's hooked.The problem is that probably you have it defined in several files (or didn't hook them).

Try to put the class in a different namespace and check if your `InitializeComponent` goes to the designer where you put the hooked functions.

Comment: yes, thank you.. I get it now... I just starting to convert all my VB code to C#... Its work now... How I close this question?

Comment: You already marked it as solved, but i'm not sure if you can close it since other people may find it useful... but i'm also new so maybe there is a way. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The "partial" keyword indicates that the code for a class can be found in multiple files. The forms designer in Visual Studio automatically creates a `Form1.Designer.cs` class where it puts the code to create controls you dragged onto the form.

- When you try to remove the `partial` keyword from `Form1`, the compiler will tell you that `Form1.Designer.cs` contains a partial definition for the same class.
- When you change the namespace, the two become separate classes, but `Form1.cs` calls `InitializeComponent()` which is defined in the other class.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author)*

> Thank you for @Tony for point me. I need to add event handler manually in C# like
>
> ```
> this.Closing += Form1_FormClosing; //for close button
> ```